# How to achieve Google map like zoom in IOS(Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am a newbie in IOS and i have a typical problem of how to achieve google map like zoom in my project. The zoom that i want is on the image as shown below. For example - If i click on the first button the whole image should zoom focussing on the first button

[image: Note : There are invisible buttons on each eight cell]

Comment: You can use MapView. In built functionality of Zoom in and out. Y r u going for google map.?

Comment: I don't want to integrate map in my project , i just want to implement zoom similar to google map.

Comment: Ohhh Sorry... User ScrollView and user ZoomToRect Method and Add your logic.

Comment: Okk but i don't want to use scroll view either.

Comment: For that you can use "CGAffineTransformMakeScale". But i ll prefer this functionality with ScrollView.